# Can I print only one of these questions at a time?

Tags: python, random

I need to randomise some questions and get one question at a time. I have about 200 questions in my list and I want my python code to randomly pick one out of the 200. I then want it to remove all questions that have already been printed from the list so that they cannot show up again. My current code randomises the order in which these questions come out. Is there a way to make it so the first question in the output is printed and then the second is printed and then the third one at a time? This is how my code looks (except with 200 questions):

```
import random

questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak',
    'define whatever',
]

while questions:

    index = random.randrange(0, len(questions))

    selected = questions[index]
    questions.pop(index)
    
    print(selected)
```

And my output(which will look different every time it’s run because its random) looks like this

```
define czech
define math
define whatever
define french
define english
define slovak
define spanish
```

Can I make it so ‘define czech’ is printed on its own and then when I run the code again, ‘define math’ comes up and then ‘define whatever’ comes up in that randomised order? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can put your codes which are inside the loop into a function and call that function when its needed

Comment: Do you need to ensure that the same question does not appear twice?

Comment: A possible one liner: `print(questions[random.randrange(0,len(questions))])`

Comment: @Heikki yes, I need to ensure that the same question does not appear twice but I also want only one question to print at a time when I run the code

Comment: you want to randomize list order then print it in original order?

Comment: One-liner from @CYREX  is even better: `print(random.choice(questions))`

Comment: @Heikki. Your one liner is  almost perfect except, before every single one of the questions have been printed , some show up twice. I need my code to only print a question once until the entire list has been printed

Comment: @CYREX. Your one liner is  almost perfect except, before every single one of the questions have been printed , some show up twice. I need my code to only print a question once until the entire list has been printed

Comment: @CYREX, yes. I want to randomise the list and then print the questions one by one from top to bottom. Another way to achieve the same effect ( no object in list showing up more then once until every object in the list has shown up once) would also be good. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. You can use generator :) See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**random.choice** to choose one element at a time and **random.choices** with choices limit, to pick up how many elements to choose, here i set it to 3. And picked_questions list will check if the question is repeated or not.

```
import random

questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak']
    
elems = random.choices(questions, k=3) # using choices this time and limit them to pick up 3 random elements you can set it to 1 to meet ur needs.i just wanna show u a method which match ur actual and next needs

picked_questions = ["define english", "define spanish", "define slovak"] # suppose those questions are already picked to check the condition success

for i in elems:
  for x in picked_questions:
    if i not in picked_questions:
      picked_questions.append(i)  # this could be optimized using list comprehension

print(elems, '\n') 
print(picked_questions)
```

random output with 3 choices

```
['define english', 'define math', 'define czech'] # 3 random elements are picked up

['define english', 'define spanish', 'define slovak', 'define math', 'define czech'] # no repeated questions, math and czech questions are appended coz they are not repeated.
```

random output with 1 choice by setting k = 1

```
['define czech'] 

['define english', 'define spanish', 'define slovak', 'define czech']
```

successfully done

Comment: This almost works except an object in the list comes up twice before all the other objects in the list have come up at least once. I need each object in the list to be printed once before any of them get printed more than once. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.remove` to remove used question and `yield` to return random question and stop.

```py
import random

questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak',
    'define whatever',
]


def question_generator(data):
    while data:
        out_q = random.choice(data)
        yield out_q
        data.remove(out_q)


out_question = question_generator(questions)
```

Now you can just call next to get random question until no more data

```py
try:
    random_question = next(out_question)
    print(random_question)

except StopIteration:
     print('No more questions')
     random_question = None

# do other stuff here. 
# call again (Best to run in try except StopIteration, as that is raise if we have consumed all questions.

another_q = next(out_question) 
print(another_q)
```

The idea is to use something like asynchronously flow. Yield will give us the value and pause the flow until we resume again. When no more values are left, `StopIteration`. error is raise. Now we catch it and return `None`.

Comment: This randomised the questions but still prints all the questions instead of just one. Is there a way for just one to be printed at a time? Thank you for replying!

Comment: Fixed now! Using generator. I did not understand the question to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I’ll definitely try it out when I have the time!

Answer (score 0):

use `random.shuffle`, with O(1) in space complexity(if shuffle in-place) and O(n) time complexity.

`random_questions` is what you want

```py
import random

origin_questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak',
    'define whatever',
]
random_questions = origin_questions[:]
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(random_questions)
    print(random_questions)
```

output

```
['define english', 'define french', 'define czech', 'define math', 'define spanish', 'define whatever', 'define slovak']
['define spanish', 'define czech', 'define french', 'define whatever', 'define math', 'define slovak', 'define english']
['define math', 'define english', 'define slovak', 'define whatever', 'define czech', 'define french', 'define spanish']
['define spanish', 'define czech', 'define english', 'define math', 'define whatever', 'define slovak', 'define french']
['define math', 'define slovak', 'define french', 'define whatever', 'define spanish', 'define english', 'define czech']
['define slovak', 'define whatever', 'define english', 'define spanish', 'define math', 'define czech', 'define french']
['define spanish', 'define math', 'define french', 'define slovak', 'define english', 'define czech', 'define whatever']
['define math', 'define whatever', 'define czech', 'define spanish', 'define french', 'define english', 'define slovak']
['define spanish', 'define math', 'define english', 'define slovak', 'define czech', 'define whatever', 'define french']
['define whatever', 'define english', 'define french', 'define spanish', 'define czech', 'define math', 'define slovak']
```

**EDIT:**
generator recipe

```py
import random

questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak',
    'define whatever',
]

def gen_random_questions(origin_questions):
    random_questions = origin_questions[:]
    random.shuffle(random_questions)
    for i in random_questions:
        yield i
        
for question in gen_random_questions(questions):
    print(question)
```

output

```
define whatever
define spanish
define english
define slovak
define french
define math
define czech
```

Comment: This is almost perfect except I need only one question to appear at a time. So like the first question in the randomised output comes on its own and then the second question in the randomised output will come on its own when I run it agaim

Comment: @Mancoder I think if you want to use a list ,just iterate over it, no worth to wrap with a function or generator, but I'm still glad to give you a demo